# Google Sheets How to get remaining amount when P.O. numbers match

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Good Morning all, New to the spreadsheet world and have ran in to a problem. What I'm trying to do is have a formula in the E column of the PO info sheet that will subtract the grand total (O column on invoice submission sheet) from the PO total (C column PO info sheet) when the PO numbers match on both sheets. Appreciate any help

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wsD9xaITn2k-Afp8nhD1kN5UyJ1efRYtYJ87zTFDdsk/edit#gid=0

Comment: I have posted an answer, but it seems there are multiple entries for the same PO number. Would you want these handled a certain way? IE use the max value, min value, or possibly the sum of them?

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed this response. I would like it so anytime a PO matches it will Subtract from the total so I know how much is left on that PO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

`=ifna(C2-vlookup(B2, 'Invoice Submission'!B2:O, 14,0))`

Place it in cell `E2` of you PO sheet, and drag down. I have placed it in your sheet and it currently works.

---

##### To subtract the total of each entry:

`=ifna(C2-sum(filter('Invoice Submission'!O2:O, 'Invoice Submission'!B2:B=B2)))`

Comment: @oarsa5 I have edited my answer so that the formula subtracts each entry

Answer (score 0):

you can use sumif for this like that

=C2-SUMIF('Invoice Submission'!B:B,B2,'Invoice Submission'!O:O)